Prove that $2^n + 65 \nmid 5^n - 3^n$, for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$
My first idea was to prove it by contradiction, assuming that $\exists n$. But I couldn't go very far. The only conclusion I reached is that $n$ necessarily have to be odd.

How did you deduce $n$ must be odd?

We already have answers showing how to quickly prove this using quadratic reciprocity (Jacobi symbol), e.g. use the same proof as here, which is the same method used in solution $2$ in the official contest solution linked below.

I don't have enough reputation to comment, so I'll just leave this as an answer.
The problem is from the 2022 IMO Shortlist, and you may check a full write-up of the solution here or on the official booklet, so far, you got an important condition, $n$ is odd, but to conclude, notice that if $5^n - 3^n$ was divisible by $2^n + 65$, then both remainders obtained by dividing $5^n$ and $3^n$ by $2^n +65$ would be equal (obvious), but something less obvious is that this also imply that both of them are non-QR/QR $\mod 2^n + 65$ at the same time.
To make this more concrete, compute $\left(\frac{5}{2^n+65}\right)$ and $\left(\frac{3}{2^n+65}\right)$ to derive a contradiction (where $\left(\frac{}{}\right)$ is the Jacobi symbol)

This problem is the N8 of the IMO Shortlist of 2022. You can find two solutions at the end of this pdf: https://www.imo-official.org/problems/IMO2022SL.pdf.
